# Nodejs Web content updated by user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, joomla, content-management-system

I am new in nodeJS and building my first webapps. I have a question. Is there a way how user can add an article to the nodeJS built web app ? Similer like when using joomla CMS. Is there a way for node web app to log to backend or does it have to be through online form ?

Thanks a lot.

BR

David

Comment: http://keystonejs.com/

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search shows you there are a lot of content management systems for nodejs.

If you're using a particular javascript framework, please search for it.

This is a very broad topic, and google is the right place to search for this.

Comment: Thanks, found it on google. I was searching wrong words. Thanks.